# Promoting docker web app to production on Heroku pipeline gives me an error

Tags: docker, heroku, deployment, continuous-integration

I've created a web app (ASP.NET Core API project, if it matters) and deployed it to Heroku as a docker container (using `heroku.yml`). That worked fine (with some obstacles that I solved).

Then I created the Heroku pipeline to have app in different environments (dev, stage, prod). I connected Heroku pipeline with the GitHub repo where my project is stored. So that gave me the staging environment of my app which works fine and opens in browser.

However, when I try to `Promote to production` from the staging environment I get the error:

`Pipeline promotions are not supported on apps pushed via Heroku Container Registry`

I am newbie to Heroku and also not expert on Docker. But why do I get this error? Why is not possible to use promotion from staging to production in a Heroku pipeline when app is deployed via docker?

Are there other options to create environments on Heroku when deploying apps via docker containers?